# Understanding of a gRPC Transcoding syntax

Tags: api, http, grpc

I'm trying to use Google API's. I found a method:

```
GET https://analyticsadmin.googleapis.com/v1beta/{parent=properties/*}/conversionEvents
```

With a mark:
`The URL uses gRPC Transcoding syntax.`

I need put my value after `properties`.

But I don't understand, how I can send a HTTP request like via Postman. I read article from API but still can't get it. Tried with  `https://analyticsadmin.googleapis.com/v1beta/parent="properties/3177281"/conversionEvents`

But always got 404 Not Found

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the Analytics Admin API but, you should replace `{parent=properties/*}` with the value `properties/3177281` so it should be `https://analyticsadmin.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/3177281/conversionEvents`

Comment: The APi **doesn't** appear to be published to Google's excellent [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) but usually (!) you could use this tool to browse APIs and methods and (often) create the API request in the browser using Google's "Try it" tool.

Comment: If you want to minimize the complexity in crafting REST (gRPC) calls directly, Google's client libraries are excellent and there are libraries for the [Google Admin Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/client-libraries)

Comment: @DazWilkin, it works! I thought that `parent` its a query param name.

Comment: I'm pleased to hear it. Yes, that's an easy mistake to make

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For posterity:

Replace `{parent=properties/*}` with the value `properties/3177281`

So the URL should be:

https://analyticsadmin.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/3177281/conversionEvents